# AWS Macie - list of query fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, lucene, amazon-macie

In the AWS Macie documentation, it shows an [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/macie/latest/userguide/macie-alerts.html#macie-alert-working-edit-add-basic) of adding a basic alert.

The example query to add is `s3_world_readability:"true"`

Where do we find a list of valid fields that we can query on?

The docs refer to  [Constructing Queries in Macie](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/macie/latest/userguide/macie-research.html#macie-query), but nowhere do I see any listing of what fields I can query.

I'm trying to figure out whether I can create Macie alert if a Bucket doesn't have a bucket policy that enforces [Server Side Encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html)

Am I missing something obvious?

#### Update

Found out you can get some suggestions from the Macie console in the Research tab.
[image]

Using this pattern when selecting S3 bucket properties, I'm able to drill down into the bucket policy.

My Bucket policy is

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy123456789",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can use the following query in Macie and it will return the bucket with this policy

```
policy.Policy.Statement.Action:"s3:PutObject"
```

So if want to query bucket policies that match the Conditions forcing SSE, I try:

```
policy.Policy.Statement.Condition.StringNotEquals.s3\:x\-amz\-server\-side\-encryption:"AES256"
```

But I get nothing back. Is there a better way for me to query these properties?